# linq xml parsing to create checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq, parsing

Hi I have a dictionary object implemented:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    ...
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dictionarycheck = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public Window1()
    {
        Dictionarycheck.Add("Execbuildstartingmail", "Execbuildstartingmail");
        Dictionarycheck.Add("Execbuildlastmail", "Execbuildlastmail");
        ...
    }
}
```

then I have xml file to be parsed. I have more than 1 of such target to be parsed. I am supposed to parse the string of the attribute "if" so over here i would need "Execexample" as a string.

```
<project>
...
   <target if="Execexample">
   ...
   </target>
...
</project>
```

To do this parsing i tried to implement this code (which i'm not sure if it is correct):

```
private void xmlparsingButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Build.xml");
    var abc = from target in xmlDoc.Descendants("target")
              select (string)target.Attribute("if");
    foreach(string target in abc)
    {
        // check this value whether if it exist in the dictionary. 
        // if not create a checkbox for it.
    }                      
}
```

For the "foreach" statement i am supposed to do a check with the dictionary object. If there is no such value in dictionary, i will create a checkbox in my tabitem 5 and the name as the string (for example ExecexamplecheckBox).

how should i implement such a foreach function?

EDIT 1:
I forgot to add something. I need to write a text to a text file if these new checkboxes are checked. How do i do that? And they are required to write to a textfile that was written previously.

Comment: @jeremychan, Still digesting your question, but it seems that you should/could be using a HashSet<string> rather than a Dictionary<string, string>.

Comment: @jackiekirby hi thanks for your input, i will go read up on that

Comment: @jeremychan, how do you know the checkbox? That is what is the name of the checkbox? Is it the name of your Dictionary item? Also, please be very clear about what you need to know/learn. It look like you're expecting a complete working solution rather than just sample code that can help you get there.

Comment: @jeremychan, you say "I need to write a line to a text file if the checkbox is checked, how do I do that?". Do what, write a line ot a text file or see if a checkbox is checked, or find a checkbox and see if it is checked?

Comment: @shiv kumar, hi i'm just not sure if u understand my question completely, therefore i have to make sure i ask the questions regarding your solutions

Comment: @shiv kumar, i am not just asking for a solution. I am totally lost when implementing "creating new checkbox and make sure they write lines to an existing textfile"

Comment: @jeremychan, ok, I can understand that you need help. That's not a problem. But please state clearly where and to what extent you need help. For example. I need help, figuring out how to see if a checkbox is checked. Or, I need help in figuring out how to write some text to a file. Or I need to figure out how to write some text to a file each time a checkbox is checked. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: @shiv kumar, thanks for your help. I think benpearce best described my problem. I am confused between the UI and databinding problem

Answer (score 0):

With the looks of it, as @Jackie mentioned, you could use HashSet. It won't make a difference except that it is the correct used of the right data structure in this case.

```
  var filePath = "PathAndFileNameOfSomeFile.txt";
  var hashset = new HashSet<string> { { "Execbuildstartingmail" }, { "Execbuildlastmail" } };
  var xmlString = "<project><target if=\"Execexample\"></target><target if=\"Execbuildlastmail\"></target></project>";
  var xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
  var attributeValues = from attrs in xDocument.Descendants("target").Attributes("if")
                        select attrs.Value;

  foreach (var value in attributeValues)
  {
    var controls = this.Controls.Find(value, true);
    //No checkbox with matching name found
    if (controls.Length == 0)
    {
      if (!hashset.Contains(value))
      {
          var checkbox = new CheckBox();
          checkbox.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage2"];
          checkbox.Text = value;          
      }
    }
      //checkbox with the given name was found AND is checked
    else if (controls.Length == 1 && ((CheckBox)controls[0]).Checked)
    {
      using (var writer = File.AppendText(filePath))
      {
        writer.WriteLine(value);
      }
    }
  }
```

**After your Edit**
I'm not clear about what you're saying in your edit, so I'll rephrase it...
While inthe foreach, if the checkbox exists and is checked, then you need to write some test to a text file. If they are not check there is nothing to do. If a checkbox does not exist, then add it to the tab is that correct?

I've updated the code to show you how to do three things:

1. Find Checkboxes in your form.
2. See if a checkbox is checked or not
3. Write some text to a text file.

even of the code I've provided does not do "Exactly" what you want I believe the various parts should help you get to your end goal. If not then please simply your question and provide very clear statements of where specifically you need help.

Comment: hi shiv kumar, thanks for your input. My question was how to implement the foreach statement to check with the dictionary values. anyway, my xml file content will always change, therefore i can't hardcode the way u do. please check my edit!

Comment: @jeremychan, In my example code, I'm using a string variable (xmlString) as an example so I could write the code and test it before I posted it here. It is an "example" so take what you need from it.

Comment: sorry if i confused you. I already have Checkboxes created (hard coded) and what they do is that if they are checked they will be write text into a text file. in this "Foreach" statement, i will want to do a check with dictionary or hashset... if these are not found in dictionary or hash set, checkbox will be created. (this is because those hardcoded checkbox are added into the dictionary or hashset) also once these new checkboxes are created and they are checked, they will write lines into the same textfile as what the hardcoded checkboxes would do if they are checked.

Comment: the "foreach" statement is not used to check if the hardcoded checkboxes are checked because i already have codes written for those already

Comment: @jeremychan, I've updated my answer and the code. Please see if this help. Essentially I've provided code for the various things you're trying to do.

Comment: @shiv kumar, hi i can't create a checkbox using this line in wpf `checkbox.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages["tabPage2"];` can u please explain to me why do u need `.parent`?

Comment: @jeremychan try adding the the checkbox using the controls collection, by doing a xxx.Controls.Add(checkbox). Where xxx is the instance of your tab page

Comment: @shiv kumar, intellisense does not give me an option of .Controls

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve the problem?

```
foreach(string target in abc)
{
  //check this value whether if it exist in the dictionary. if not create a checkbox for it.
  if (!Dictionarycheck.ContainsKey(target))
  {
    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Text = target;
    SomePanel.Controls.Add(chk);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, just got a question. what does this SomePanel.Controls.Add(chk) do?

Comment: `SomePanel` is the Control upon which you want to put your `CheckBox`. Controls.Add means your added a control onto `SomePanel`. `chk` mean you are adding a `chk` to `SomePanel`.

Comment: @jeremychan does the above answer your question?

Comment: @funmunpieng sorry im still in the middle of trying out other solutions. will update you

Comment: @funmunpieng i have a tabitem with a grid definded. how do i add the control in it?? i tried `tabitem5.Controls.Add(chk);` doesnt work

Comment: when you say doesn't work, what do you mean? you can't compile? it throws an exception? if exception, what does the exception say? Any error? or it simply does nothing?

Comment: As in when i tried to do tabitem5.controls, intellisense does not give me an option of Controls

Comment: 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) that is the error

Comment: I dont know how to see what class it is but when i highlight tabitem5 in xaml view the tooltip shows System.Windows.Controls.TabItem

Comment: It is not typical to add a checkbox to tabitems in a tabControl. You should probably start a new question on this.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two separate problems here:

1 - Data problem
  Parse the xml file and extract the necessary data to a seperate list or dictionary.

2 - User interface
  Generate a series of checkboxes based on the output of the data problem.

First you should separate the data problem away from the UI. In the foreach loop build a list of objects. The object should have at least a string property, for display, and a boolean property for the checkbox to bind to.

Second, on your UI create a ItemsControl (such as a ListBox) and bind its ItemsSource to the above list, then set the ItemTemplate to a DataTemplate containing a CheckBox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SomeList}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=DisplayString}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

After the user has finished checking/unchecking the list, you will be left with a list upon which to write your text lines to a file.

There are several concepts you should learn when dealing with WPF, probably the hardest to get your head around is the seperation of concern between the UI and the data, and how the data layer can feed the UI to create elements for you. There should be no need to create new checkboxes in code using this technique.

Also, you will be better off not binding directly to a dictionary (although it is [possible](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/)) but you should use ObservableCollection as your ItemsSource, it will handle change notification to the UI for you.

Comment: What do you mean by binding to xaml? The concept in my code is basic binding concepts in WPF - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx and basic data templating - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx